# How to create URL link to the specific section of the PDF file?

Tags: pdf, url, hyperlink

I am trying to create a pointer link to a specific section of the PDF file which is in my local directory.

Normally I create hyperlinks to the pages like that.

```
xyz.pdf#page=4
```

But I cannot figure out how can I point sections of the book with URL. For example, the following hyperlinks point to the somewhere of the book. I want to know what is the URL syntax for accessing these sections.

```
2 Intelligent Agents 34
2.1 Agents and Environments . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 34
2.2 Good Behavior: The Concept of Rationality . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 36
2.3 The Nature of Environments . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 40
2.4 The Structure of Agents . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 46
2.5 Summary, Bibliographical and Historical Notes, Exercises . . . . . . . . . 59
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, what is usually referred to as chapters or sections inside a PDF, are *bookmarks*. According to Adobe's [Parameters for Opening PDF Files](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=5), there are only two official ways of opening a PDF on specified position, and bookmarks are not there:

1. **Named destination**. Depending on your PDF viewer, you need to find a list of so-called *destinations* in your document and use the desired one (there should be no white spaces):

   `[PDF file](./xyz.pdf#[destination name])`
2. **Specific page**. The method you are already aware of:

   `[PDF file](./xyz.pdf#page=[page number])`

IMO the easiest and robust way is just to stick with page numbers, also due to URL limitations (from the [same document](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=8)):

> Individual parameters, together with their values (separated by & or #), can be no greater then 32 characters in length.

Comment: Is there a way to create destinations from Word? My issue is that I have a 200 page document that changes periodically and have links to specific sections all over other documents and websites. Anytime the document changes, all those links now point to page numbers that are inaccurate, so I'd like to be able to point to destinations instead.

Comment: @dylanmurphy Sorry, I don't use MS Word, only LaTeX and occasionally LO Writer. Probably you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Asked and answered `here` (by me) because I had the same issue. But I walked through how to accomplish it a little more in detail:

1. Take your document and set it up with links that Acrobat can recognize, in the link above I talk about how to do this for Word.
2. Export that to PDF. Make sure that the links work in the PDF when clicked.
3. Download AutoBookmark Plug-in. Follow great directions in link to
   turn the PDF links into Named Destinations.
4. (Optional) The section headings/link text in my document had spaces,
   super long names, and other things that don't work with the
   parameters provided by Adobe in 2007. So I exported all the
   bookmarks that AutoBookmark made, did some find/replace regular
   expression magic to the text file, deleted all the bookmarks in the
   pdf, then imported my cleaned up text file.
5. Finally, post pdf online and link to it like so: path/file.pdf#nameddest="bookmark"

As long as the Named Destinations don't change names, it doesn't matter where in the document they live, as long as steps 1-4 are followed your URLs should be resilient. If you have a similar situation and have questions about the regex stuff or formatting etc., I'd be glad to share screenshots or add more detail to clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

A technique I often use to make links to online PDF documents like Data Sheets is to copy a link that exists in the document (e.g. in the table of contents) using right-click copy link in Firefox. It's ready to be pasted in an answer or comment. If unsure, I test the link in a new private window.

The links thus obtained typically are in format 1 of the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1384902/221661).

Example: This links to [table 3](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN91378_HX3_Hardware_Design_Guidelines_and_Schematic_Checklist-ApplicationNotes-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073c6ed2607c#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A23%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C51%2C336%2C0%5D) was copied from the reference below [figure 1](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN91378_HX3_Hardware_Design_Guidelines_and_Schematic_Checklist-ApplicationNotes-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073c6ed2607c#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A23%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C51%2C703%2C0%5D).