# How to create URL Link to specific text (not page) in PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, url

This is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1384892/how-to-create-url-link-to-the-specific-section-of-the-pdf-file/1384902) but different enough to be asked I think. I have a ~200 page Word document that is regularly updated and contains Chapters, Sections, Subsections and Citations. This document is then turned into a PDF, which is published online for the public's consumption.

There is a requirement that the public needs to be able to get to specific citations in the PDF with one click, no searching. Initially, we had the path/file.pdf#page="###" URLs set up which works okay, except that someone has to manually find which page each of the hundreds of citations is on, then make the URL and add it to the appropriate docs/websites/etc. This was fine until the first document update added some sections and removed others, causing all of the path/file.pdf#page="###" URLS to be off by up to ten pages in either direction.

What I'm looking for is a way to take a Word document with a automatically generated Table of Contents, export that as a PDF, and then use those bookmarks/links as URLS that can be shared elsewhere. It is also a requirement that these links remain functional and still pointing to the desired resource after revisions have taken place.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I'm aware of to do this:

1. Take your Word document and set it up with a Table of Contents field (ideally by using proper styles/headings but up to you).
2. Export that to PDF. Make sure that the links from the Table of Contents work in the PDF when clicked.
3. Download [AutoBookmark Plug-in](https://www.evermap.com/abm_dst_summary.asp#Creating%20Destinations%20From%20Links). Follow great directions in link to turn the PDF links into Named Destinations.
4. (Optional) The section headings/link text in my document had spaces, super long names, and other things that don't work with the [parameters](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=5) provided by Adobe in 2007. So I exported all the bookmarks that AutoBookmark made, did some find/replace regular expression magic to the text file, deleted all the bookmarks in the pdf, then imported my cleaned up text file.
5. Finally, post pdf online and link to it like so: path/file.pdf#nameddest="bookmark"

As long as the Named Destinations don't change names, it doesn't matter where in the document they live, as long as steps 1-4 are followed your URLs should be resilient. If you have a similar situation and have questions about the regex stuff or formatting etc., I'd be glad to share screenshots or add more detail to clear this up.